# Missingno heatmap line / border color

Tags: python, missingno

I use missingno `heatmap` visualization and would like to add a line \ border to show the different values. While I can adjust the font size, e.g. `msno.heatmap(df, fontsize=20)`. I couldn't find a way to adjust this property from the heatmap creating method. The following attempts yield `TypeError` -

```
msno.heatmap(df, linecolor='black') 
msno.heatmap(df, line_color='black') 
msno.heatmap(df, bordercolor='black') 
msno.heatmap(df, border_color='black')
```

Comment: Pushed my own fixed here for now - https://github.com/tomron/missingno/tree/add_heatmap_args_param